# How to increase width of row in a html table

Tags: html, css

How do I increase the width of the task column to fit more than 10 words in one row
Pasting my whole code here just in case - it's not clear in the snippet

https://jsfiddle.net/0jna9mrb/

```html
<table style="margin: 8px 18px 18px 8px;">
  <div data-block-id="6a64bca8-54a9-4c5f-9e2d-9d570a255ee7" class="dailyos-selectable dailyos-table-block dailyos-table-tbody-selectable" style="position: relative;">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="dailyos-table-row">
        <td style="background: rgb(247, 246, 243); font-weight: 500; border: 1px solid rgb(233, 233, 231); position: relative; vertical-align: top; min-width: 122px; max-width: 122px; min-height: 32px;">
          <div class="dailyos-table-cell">
            <div class="dailyos-table-cell-text" spellcheck="true" placeholder=" " data-content-editable-leaf="true" style="max-width: 100%; width: 100%; white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-word; caret-color: rgb(55, 53, 47); padding: 7px 9px; background-color: transparent; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;"
              contenteditable="false">Time</div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td style="background: rgb(247, 246, 243); font-weight: 500; border: 1px solid rgb(233, 233, 231); position: relative; vertical-align: top; min-width: 200px; max-width: 200px; min-height: 32px;">
          <div class="dailyos-table-cell">
            <div class="dailyos-table-cell-text" spellcheck="true" placeholder=" " data-content-editable-leaf="true" style="max-width: 100%; width: 100%; white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-word; caret-color: rgb(55, 53, 47); padding: 7px 9px; background-color: transparent; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;"
              contenteditable="false">Task</div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="dailyos-table-row">
        <td style="color: inherit; fill: inherit; border: 1px solid rgb(233, 233, 231); position: relative; vertical-align: top; min-width: 122px; max-width: 122px; min-height: 32px;">
          <div class="dailyos-table-cell">
            <div class="dailyos-table-cell-text" spellcheck="true" placeholder=" " data-content-editable-leaf="true" style="max-width: 100%; width: 100%; white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-word; caret-color: rgb(55, 53, 47); padding: 7px 9px; background-color: transparent; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;"
              contenteditable="false">6 AM</div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td style="color: inherit; fill: inherit; border: 1px solid rgb(233, 233, 231); position: relative; vertical-align: top; min-width: 200px; max-width: 200px; min-height: 32px;">
          <div class="dailyos-table-cell">
            <div class="dailyos-table-cell-text" spellcheck="true" placeholder=" " data-content-editable-leaf="true" style="max-width: 100%; width: 100%; white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-word; caret-color: rgb(55, 53, 47); padding: 7px 9px; background-color: transparent; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;"
              <section id="6am_input" contenteditable="true"></div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: 0

You are assigning 100% width in the inner <div> of the <td>. But in every <td> tag has min-width and max-width property width specific px value. then how can the width:100% of inner div work.

Comment: @SaikatRoy https://jsfiddle.net/0jna9mrb/ - You can check whole code here and let me know also can you tell me how I can center allign all of this ?

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are trying to do?

```html
<div>
  <table style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
    <div data-block-id="6a64bca8-54a9-4c5f-9e2d-9d570a255ee7"
      class="dailyos-selectable dailyos-table-block dailyos-table-tbody-selectable"
      style="position: relative;">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="dailyos-table-row">
          <td
            style="background: rgb(247, 246, 243); font-weight: 500; border: 1px solid rgb(233, 233, 231); position: relative; vertical-align: top; min-width: 122px; min-height: 32px;">
            <div class="dailyos-table-cell">
              <div class="dailyos-table-cell-text" spellcheck="true"
                placeholder=" " data-content-editable-leaf="true"
                style="white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-word; caret-color: rgb(55, 53, 47); padding: 7px 9px; background-color: transparent; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;"
                contenteditable="false">Time</div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td
            style="background: rgb(247, 246, 243); font-weight: 500; border: 1px solid rgb(233, 233, 231); position: relative; vertical-align: top; min-width: 200px; min-height: 32px;">
            <div class="dailyos-table-cell">
              <div class="dailyos-table-cell-text" spellcheck="true"
                placeholder=" " data-content-editable-leaf="true"
                style="max-width: 100%; width: 100%; white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-word; caret-color: rgb(55, 53, 47); padding: 7px 9px; background-color: transparent; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;"
                contenteditable="false">Task</div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dailyos-table-row">
          <td
            style="color: inherit; fill: inherit; border: 1px solid rgb(233, 233, 231); position: relative; vertical-align: top; min-width: 122px; min-height: 32px;">
            <div class="dailyos-table-cell">
              <div class="dailyos-table-cell-text" spellcheck="true"
                placeholder=" " data-content-editable-leaf="true"
                style="white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-word; caret-color: rgb(55, 53, 47); padding: 7px 9px; background-color: transparent; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;"
                contenteditable="false">6 AM</div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td
            style="color: inherit; fill: inherit; border: 1px solid rgb(233, 233, 231); position: relative; vertical-align: top; min-width: 200px; min-height: 32px;">
            <div class="dailyos-table-cell">
              <div class="dailyos-table-cell-text" spellcheck="true"
                placeholder=" " data-content-editable-leaf="true"
                style="white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-word; caret-color: rgb(55, 53, 47); padding: 7px 9px; background-color: transparent; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;"
                <section id="6am_input" contenteditable="true"></div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        
      </tbody>
    </div>
  </table>
</div>
```